# Where is the variable hero damage in DOTA2?

Tags: dota-2

In Dota, heroes had variable base damage. I particularly loved CK's starting damage (49-79). Though it was tough in last hitting creeps, it was very useful while fighting heroes 1 on 1 early game.

Are the hero damage still a range of damage ? Because all I can see on the HUD is a rounded number.

Comment: Not certain but I think the developers of Dota 2 tried to reduce/remove the amount of RNG (AKA luck factors) in the game. But that's mostly based on what I think I heard lol.

Comment: I don't think it has been; if you hover over the sword, you can see the upper and lower boundaries.

Comment: why the hell do you downvote this? it's a good question

Comment: @RayofCommand Unfortunately it's not. It's a question about why a developer did something. Unless the developer himself shows up to answer, most answers are going to be speculation.

Comment: @Studoku Its not that only the developer would know the answer to it. And according to the answer, the developer didnt remove it. So I suppose its a pretty valid question. Very few people would know that its still there.

Comment: @MandeepJain Your welcome. I'll up vote it now, as the edit does the question justice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroes still have a damage range, it's just not shown in the UI unless you mouse over.

Here's a useful site that shows the stats in full in a sortable view (show the min damage, max damage, and average damage columns): http://www.devilesk.com/dota2/heroes/herodata

Comment: dont understand the reason for showing the average damage then. Not a good UI. All time long I thought it had been removed. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. I played 1,346 hours of DotA2 and thought those ranges were gone! I did hover over a lot of times but only for the attack range or attack speed. I completely missed the range...

Comment: Exactly the same @Wandang. so many times i have hovered over it and it was there all along :P

Comment: Also http://www.buildota2.com/build_creation?hero_name=leshrac shows data about heroes - DPS, min damage, max damage etc.